# Lambda Expression : use function result as next parameter in a map

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-stream

I have a function in my mapper with several parameter: function(A,B,C)
All of them are coming from differents functions, all in the same service, but parameter B and C need the result of parameter A

```
   service.getRequests()
            .stream()
            .map(r ->
                mapper.function(
                    service.getAList(r), //return List<A> aList
                    service.getBList(aList), //use the previous aList as parameter
                    service.getCList(aList) //same
            )
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can enclose the block of code within braces `.map(r -> {
                List<A> aList = service.getAList(r);
                return mapper.function(
                    aList, //return List<A> aList
                    service.getBList(aList), //use the previous aList as parameter
                    service.getCList(aList) //same
            );})`

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
.map(r -> {
    List<A> aList = service.getAList(r);
    return mapper.function(
        aList,
        service.getBList(aList),
        service.getCList(aList);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to move this functionality into a separate method:

```java
private MapperResult remap(Request request) {
    List<A> resultA = service.getAList(request);

    return mapper.function(
        resultA,
        service.getBList(resultA),
        service.getCList(resultA)
    );
}
```

And then use a reference to this method:

```java
service.getRequests()
       .stream()
       .map(MyClass::remap)
       .sorted()
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```